# How to fix error when installing annoy in python

Tags: python, word2vec

I am installing annoy in python 3.5-3.2 Windows 10 to create similarities.index. This is C++ library with Python bindings. I do this: 
pip install annoy. 
On the step c++ translation I recieved 
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2.
How to fix it?
(I know about "Issues in install annoy python package" but it does not help)

Comment: Please file a bug report upstream. If you really want to ask here, turn that into an actual programming question by extracting a [mcve]. As it stands, there's way too little info (e.g. what is the commandline the compiler is invoked with?) to make guesses.

Answer (score 0):

I am not shure that this is universal but now it works:
Under Windows 10 Visula studio 2017 with c++ and python 3.6 is installed. And I use Python 3.7 64. Annoy installed by pip install annoy and simple script was run:

```
from gensim.similarities.index import AnnoyIndexer
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

sentences = [['cute', 'cat', 'say', 'meow'], ['cute', 'dog', 'say', 'woof']]
model = Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=1, seed=1)

indexer = AnnoyIndexer(model, 2)
x=model.most_similar("cat", topn=2, indexer=indexer)
print("cat - most similar 2 words = ",x)
```

The result is not good: cat - woof, but I think this is because very small data.